# Как сделать RegEx к htaccess

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Здраствуйте, делаю api к своему сайту, решил украсить URL, использую RewriteEngine в htaccess

Я составил такой код:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^api/v1/(.*)?\?(.*)?$ /api.php?func=$1&$2 [L]
```

Объясняю код:

`api/v1/` - директория api "в кавычках"

`(.*)?\?(.*)` - тут беру любой текст введённый пользователем, и делаю необязательный блок который появляется когда добавлен знак "?", если знак есть, то беру всё после "?"

`^` и `$` начало и конец строки

Как я хочу сделать
При запросе по адресу: /api/v1/ads/del?id=123

Нужно чтоб в $1 было ads/del
А в $2 было id=123

Но если запрос будет такой: /api/v1/ads?id=123

Я хочу получить $1=ads, $2="id=123"

Если же я перейду по: /api/v1/ads

То просто получу $1=ads,$2=""

Но перейдя по адресу `/api/v1/qwerty?qwe=123`
В переменную $1 и $2 записывается qwerty?qwe=123
Хотя должно `$1=qwerty, $2="qwe=123"`
[image: скриншот]

Как такое сделать ума не приложу
Как только не пробовал
Часа три с этим борюсь

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: на флаги `QSA` обратите внимание

Comment: Можно поподробнее?
Я сейчас гуглю что это
Добавьте ответ, чтоб я его отметил как решение

Comment: Спасибо, я нашёл ответ.
Оставьте ответ, я его отмечу как решение

Answer (score 1):

Я сделал следующие

```
RewriteRule ^api/v1/(.*)$ /api.php?func=$1 [QSA, L]
```

Таким образом при обращении к `api/v1/hell?return=true` это будет как `api.php?func=hell&return=true`